# Cannot read file from azure databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am running this command to read data from Azure databricks from a plain cluster (hadoop not installed).

```sh
spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0 \
  --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
  --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" \
  --conf "spark.delta.logStore.class=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.HDFSLogStore" \
  Test_write_to_DL.py
```

I am getting this error

```
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.SecureAzureBlobFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaTableUtils$.findDeltaTableRoot(DeltaTable.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource$.parsePathIdentifier(DeltaDataSource.scala:259)
```

Can you please suggest what jar I need to install in order to get this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Delta [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#microsoft-azure-storage) for details:

1. First, instead of `org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.HDFSLogStore`, you need to use `org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.AzureLogStore`
2. You need to include `hadoop-azure` package ([maven coordinates](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure)) into `--packages`
3. You also need to provide credentials, etc.